# Change URL NextGEN Gallery Plugin

Tags: wordpress

We are using the NextGen Gallery plugin to generate a slideshow in a Wordpress site.  I needed to change the site URL to a a different subdomain, and this seems to have broken the links.  The plugin-generated javascript still passes the old URL to swfobject.embedSWF.

Does anyone know how to fix this?  I already updated the Wordpress "General Settings" with the new WordPress address and Site address (which are the same), and the plugin does not seem to pick up that change.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it.  It's in the string-encoded ngg_options entry in the wp_options table.  The specific field is "irURL".

Why they chose to capture the site URL independently, instead of reading it from the Wordpress site configuration, is beyond me.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that NextGen has hardcoded those values somewhere in its database tables?

It could be a matter of running a bunch of SQL update queries to replace any instances of http://old.domain for http://new.domain

And now I'll state the obvious, recommending you to backup the full DB before you attempt any of this.

Comment: Good suggestion, but the 'wp_ngg_gallery' database table's path column just contains the relative path.  Thanks.

Comment: Actually, it's in the JSON-encoded ngg_options entry the wp_options table.  The specific option is "irURL".

Comment: .. and thanks for reminding me to do the database backup before editing that!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem (unchanged absolute CSS/JS files' paths) after domain changing although I changed every single old domain's occurrence in database (even in serialized arrays/objects in options).

I found solution on http://www.nextgen-gallery.com/galleries-opening-lightbox/ - I didn't have time to do an investigation where they store these paths or in which format. :P

For me it is extremely stupid in Wordpress that it stores absolute paths (with one and the same domain) in so many places but that's another matter. :)